# How are features represented in the sparse array using DictVectorizer()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-extraction

Code:

```
measurements = [
     {'city': 'Dubai', 'temperature': 33.},
     {'city': 'London', 'temperature': 12.},
     {'city': 'San Francisco', 'temperature': 18.}]
```

```
vec = DictVectorizer()
transformed_sparse = vec.fit_transform(measurements)
print(transformed_sparse)
```

Result:

```
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (0, 3)    33.0
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (1, 3)    12.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
  (2, 3)    18.0
```

The first row in the sparse array tells us about the existence of the key in the first row of the dictionary. Then why is the temperature value indexed at `(0,3)`? Does it mean the first row, third column? Shouldn't it be the second?

I was not able to find the relation between the indexing of the array and the dictionary. I have used ChatGPT, but it gives a different answer every time.

Answer (score 0):

The first three columns of the output correspond to the `city` from the input, one for each observed city; from [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html):

> When feature values are strings, this transformer will do a binary one-hot (aka one-of-K) coding: one boolean-valued feature is constructed for each of the possible string values that the feature can take on.

The last column is then the `temperature` column.

If you're using a recent version of sklearn, you can verify this with `vec.get_feature_names_out()`.